# Set building notation with vectors

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vectors

I have one set, $$M = \{(px_0,py_0,pz_0),(px_1,py_1,pz_1)...(px_n,py_n,pz_n)\}$$
and a two points
$$P = (P_x,P_y,P_z)$$
$$O = (0,0,0)$$

I would like to create a new set, which is the vectors $$\vec OP\ - \vec OM_n= \vec r_n$$

I have been googling around, and pretty sure it got it mostly correct, but would like to have some experts look at it:

$$\{ \forall\ n \in\ [0; |M|]: \vec OP\ - \vec OM_n\} = \{\vec r_n \}$$
So my reasoning is that for each n in the interval [0, length of M], we create a vector from $M_n$ to $P$ which equals $r_n$

Well thanks for taking your time for reading this, i am just a student steping way outside my school curriculum, trying to learn some more

Comment: What is $M_n$? Are the elements of $M$ and $P$ and $O$ points of $\mathbb{R}^3$? And what do you mean by the 'lenght of $M$'? the number of elements it contains?...I'm sorry, if I can't understand what you are trying to do I can't help you

Comment: @laflaca okay maybe i started my learning curve a little too steep.
$M_n$ is the n element of M, so $M_5 = (px_5, py_5, pz_5)$
Yes the elements of $M$ and $P$ and $O$ points of $\Bbb R^3$

And yes, i mean the number of elements M contain. Dont be sorry, my mistake for being to ambiguous. Maybe i should start from the bottom, and look some fundementals up instead of jumping right into it